# Win32, and the window style

Tags: c, windows, winapi

So I have a window, and I have coded it so that during run-time it can enter and exit full-screen mode. Entering full-screen works, but exiting places the window tile bar in reverse order.

Exit full screen code:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 640, 480, NULL);
InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
```

Picture of the result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p15eltz7b2hxx4y/window.png?dl=0

I tried using GWL_STYLE instead of GWL_EXSTYLE but that works even worse, with the window being visible but clicking anything on the window will act like the window is not there and the click on whatever is behind it...

Thanks!
Philip

Comment: You are mixing flags. `WS_` is for `GWL_STYLE` and `WS_EX_` is for `GWL_EXSTYLE`. You cannot just use `SetWindowLong` to blast new flags in. You need to merge them with the existing flags, or you will be manipulating flags you did not intend. For example, you accidentally cleared `WS_VISIBLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought, couldn't you get the window style (with GetWindowLongPtr), store it as a member variable in you class and then use this as the style to reset in SetWindowLongPtr?

Following is uncheck code (this is assuming you are using C++),

```
MainWnd::OnFullScreen(...)
{
     m_oldStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(GWL_EXSTYLE, m_hwd);
     /*
         what ever other code is necessary
      */
}



MainWnd::OnExitFullScreen(...)
{
    SetWindowLongPtr(m_hwn, GWL_EXSTYLE, m_oldStyle);
    /*
          and other code as needed
     */
}
```

I've made two assumptions here:

(1) that you will have two variables, one to contain the old style (m_oldStyle) and one to hold the handle to the window (m_hwd).  Note if you are doing strict SDK style coding then the handle will be passed to you as part of WndProc.  If you are using MFC there should be member function in the class you derived you main window from.  In other cases you are on your own.

(2) the second assumption is that SetWindowLongPtr is called prior to any change of screen type.  I believe that SetWindowLongPtr is called during window construction, but it has been several years since I've done serious windows programming using Microsoft frameworks (now I tend to used QT's framework).